# Rails, ActionCable, send message to Channel from server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actioncable

Is there any way to send a message to a channel from, for example, a

This command send from Server to Clients

> ActionCable.server.broadcast('test_notification_channel', {t: 1})

But I need to send from controller direct to Channel

Answer (score 0):

Although  I think that it can be done other way, including action: should work, assuming your channel has stream_for "test_notification_channel"

```
ActionCable.server.broadcast \
  "test_notification_channel", { action: "method_on_channel", t: "1" }
```

Comment: No, It did not works. Thank you for your answer! For now, I'm using a method in the model, then, I can call it from everywhere.